# Is it possible to pass samples of unequal size to function boot in R

Tags: r

I'm currently writing a tutorial about bootstrapping in `R`. I settled on the function `boot` in the `boot` package. I got the book "An introduction to the Bootstrap" by Efron/Tibshirani (1993) and just replicate a few of their examples.

Quite often in those examples, they compute statistics based on different samples. For instance, they have this one example where they have a sample of 16 mice. 7 of those mice received a treatment that was meant to prolong survival time after a test surgery. The remaining 9 mice did not receive the treatment. For each mouse, the number of days it survived was collected (values are given below).

Now, I want to use the bootstrapping approach to find out if the difference of mean is significant or not. However, if I understand the help page of `boot` correctly, I can't just pass two different samples with unequal sample size to the function. My workaround is as follows:

```
#Load package boot
library(boot)
#Read in the survival time in days for each mouse
treatment <- c(94, 197, 16, 38, 99, 141, 23)
control   <- c(52, 104, 146, 10, 51, 30, 40, 27, 46)
#Call boot twice(!)
b1 <- boot(data = treatment,
           statistic = function(x, i) {mean(x[i])},
           R = 10000)
b2 <- boot(data = control,
           statistic = function(x, i) {mean(x[i])},
           R = 10000)
#Compute difference of mean manually
mean_diff <- b1$t -b2$t
```

In my opinion, this solution is a bit of a hack. The statistic I'm interested in is now saved in a vector `mean_diff`, but I don't get all the great functionality of the `boot` package anymore. I can't call `boot.ci` on `mean_diff`, etc.

So my question basically is if my hack is the only way to do a bootstrap with the `boot` package in `R` and statistics that compare two different samples. Or is there another way?

I thought about passing one data.frame in with 16 rows and an additional column "Group":

```
df <- data.frame(survival=c(treatment, control), 
                 group=c(rep(1, length(treatment)), rep(2, length(control))))
head(df)
  survival group
1       94     1
2      197     1
3       16     1
4       38     1
5       99     1
6      141     1
```

However, now I would have to tell `boot` that it has to sample always 7 observations from the first 7 rows and 9 observations from the last 9 rows and treat these as separate samples. I would not know how to do that.

Comment: Why aren't you using `t.test`?????

Comment: @Dwin I know that I can run `t.test(df$survival ~ df$group)` as an alternative to `boot`. However, this is not my question here (I actually have that part in my tutorial). The question is about the general case in which I want to apply a bootstrap to a statistic that compares two samples. The difference of mean test was just an example. Or did you have something in mind that combines `t.test` and `boot`? In that case, it would be great if you could share that solution because I don't quite see how.

Comment: I was thinking you could use t.test(...)$t as your boot statistic if you could stratify the sampling properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving it another thought, I realized that I could actually combine Thomas' answer with `boot`. Here is a solution:

```
b <- boot(data=df, 
           statistic = function(x, i) {
             booty <- tapply(x$survival,x$group,FUN=function(x) sample(x,length(x),TRUE))
             diff(sapply(booty,mean))*-1
           },
           R=10000)
```

The trick is that the function you provide to the argument `statistic` has to accept a parameter i for the index, but that you completely ignore this parameter within your function. Instead, you do the sampling yourself. Of course, this is not the most efficient (because `boot` has to do the sampling as well), but I guess that in most cases this shouldn't be a big issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've never really figured out what the big advantage of **boot** is, since it is so easy to manually code bootstrap procedures. You could try for example the following using `replicate`:

```
myboot1 <- function(){
    booty <- tapply(df$survival,df$group,FUN=function(x) sample(x,length(x),TRUE))
    sapply(booty,mean)
}
out1 <- replicate(1000,myboot1())
```

From this you can get a bunch of useful statistics quite easily:

```
rowMeans(out1) # group means
diff(rowMeans(out1)) # difference
mean(out1[1,]-out1[2,]) # another way of getting difference
apply(out1,1,quantile,c(0.025,0.975)) # treatment-group CIs
quantile(out1[1,]-out1[2,],c(0.025,0.975)) # CI for the difference
```

Comment: As I wrote, `boot.ci` is pretty neat. Also, my "hack" doesn't look anymore complicated than yours, so it's not that `boot` makes things more complicated in the case with different samples (even if my hack is the best possible solution). But of course, you have a point. There are other solutions to run a bootstrap (like your nice one) that are not any more complicated than using `boot`.

Comment: Actually, thanks to your answer I found a way to combine it with `boot`, so +1. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is an example in `?boot.return`:

```
diff.means <- function(d, f)
{    n <- nrow(d)
     gp1 <- 1:table(as.numeric(d$series))[1]
     m1 <- sum(d[gp1,1] * f[gp1])/sum(f[gp1])
     m2 <- sum(d[-gp1,1] * f[-gp1])/sum(f[-gp1])
     ss1 <- sum(d[gp1,1]^2 * f[gp1]) - (m1 *  m1 * sum(f[gp1]))
     ss2 <- sum(d[-gp1,1]^2 * f[-gp1]) - (m2 *  m2 * sum(f[-gp1]))
     c(m1 - m2, (ss1 + ss2)/(sum(f) - 2))
}
grav1 <- gravity[as.numeric(gravity[,2]) >= 7,]
boot(grav1, diff.means, R = 999, stype = "f", strata = grav1[,2])
```

Section3.2 of Davison and Hinkley can be referenced.

Comment: I think that this example only works for samples of equal size, but it should be pretty straightforward to make it more general. I think one would just need a `gp2 <- seq(from=table(as.numeric(d$series))[1]+1,by=1, length.out=table(as.numeric(d$series))[2])` and adjust the rest accordingly. So thanks. However, this example made me wonder what `f` actually is. I thought it's something like `sample(1:26, 26, TRUE)`, but this example seems to indicate it's a vector of booleans. Now I'm a little confused...Tried to check out the source, but this looks too complicated for a Friday morning....

Comment: It can be a vector of numeric indices, logicals or weights. You  use the minus sign on from of a vector of integers to remove items from a dataframe or matrix. Notice that if these were logicals, that the "-" would not be the correct method of negation.